# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 not detected by ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, atheros

According to this page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsQualcomm) this driver should work out of the box but not for 16.04. What can I do to make wireless work on 16.04? `rfkill list` shows empty output and `ifconfig` shows no wireless interface.

Edit 1:

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

```
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
0f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Atheros AR9565 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [103c:217f]
```

Edit 2:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.5.4-040504-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath9k not found in directory /lib/modules/4.5.4-040504-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: @chili555 added

Comment: I wonder if the libkmod error is the real issue. Let's dig deeper. Please add: `sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: @chili555 added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you installed a mainline kernel image from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.4-yakkety/ Please be certain that you installed linux-headers-generic appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit; also linux-headers-generic all and, finally, linux-image-generic appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit. If any one of these three is missing, install it, reboot and then try again:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath
```

You should not see:

> FATAL: Module ath9k not found

And your wireless should now be working.